# Can I use PHP and/or htaccess to rewrite a URL but not redirect?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is there a way I can use PHP (and/or .htaccess) to rewrite the URL of a page.

For example if a user goes to www.mysite.com/french they are actually accessing the page which is www.mysite.com/index.php?lang=fr

But not a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the Apache site you can find several [examples of URL rewriting flavors](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html), by the way it's enough to use something like this in an .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^french(/|)$ /index.php?lang=fr  [flag]
```

Where `[flag]` can be one of the following:

```
[PT]
[L,PT]
[QSA]
[L,QSA]
```

You may want to have a look at the [PT (passthrough) flag docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt) or [RewriteRule flags docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html).

Also, pay attention to what your links are pointing to: in fact, the RewriteRule first argument is a regular expression that will be used to match the URLs to be rewritten. At the moment,

```
^french(/|)$
```

matches "french", right after the domain name,followed either by a slash (/) or nothing (that's the meaning of `(/|)` ); that is, it'll match www.mysite.com/french and www.mysite.com/french/ but nothing else. If you need to parse query string arguments, or subpaths, then you may need a more complex regex.

Comment: That's not what the `[PT]` flag is used for.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt

Comment: @Rocket: mod_rewrite is actually a URL-to-filename resolver.  Whatever it rewrites stuff to is, by default, the end result.  `[PT]` is a bit of a hack to allow it to do URL-to-URL rewrites that then get passed back into Apache for further processing by modules like mod_alias.  It does seem a bit out of place here, though.

Comment: @cHao: I know what `[PT]` does.  I was commenting that "stops Apache from redirecting to the page while silently loading it" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Rocket: Yeah, i didn't get that either.  I was semi wondering why i never see (or had a need to use) `[PT]` in .htaccess files, but apparently it's always on at that point.

Comment: I was wrong. It worked half the way. If I enter mysite.com/french then it works but if there is a link on the site to mysite.com/french then I get a 404 error :(

Comment: @Michael I added some extra info, btw could you post the failing URLs?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `mod_rewrite` and an .htaccess file to achieve this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^french/(.*)$ /index.php?lang=fr [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using Apache mod_rewrite and appropriate rules in an .htaccess file.

The docs on mod_rewrite are here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html